# getline check if line is whitespace

Tags: c, whitespace, getline

Is there an easy way to check if a line is empty. So i want to check if it contains any white space such as \r\n\t and spaces.

Thanks

Comment: But isspace () return value depends on the c locale installed. And so depending on that it can return false for newline or tab characters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`isspace`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isspace.html) function in a loop to check if all characters are whitespace:

```
int is_empty(const char *s) {
  while (*s != '\0') {
    if (!isspace((unsigned char)*s))
      return 0;
    s++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

This function will return 0 if any character is not whitespace (i.e. line is not empty), or 1 otherwise.

Comment: the argument to `isspace` should be cast to `unsigned char` (the is* functions "do not like" negative input and `char` may be signed): `isspace((unsigned char)*s)`

Comment: @pmg If "the is* functions "do not like" negative input", then why such functions have argument of type `int`?

Comment: @pmor: because [C11 7.4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4) says so -- "... the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 3):

If a string `s` consists only of white space characters then `strspn(s, " \r\n\t")` will return the length of the string. Therefore a simple way to check is `strspn(s, " \r\n\t") == strlen(s)` but this will traverse the string twice. You can also write a simple function that would traverse at the string only once:

```
bool isempty(const char *s)
{
  while (*s) {
    if (!isspace(*s))
      return false;
    s++;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't check for '\0' since '\0' is not space and the loop will end there.

```
int is_empty(const char *s) {
  while ( isspace( (unsigned char)*s) )
          s++;
  return *s == '\0' ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: `*s == '\0' ? 1 : 0` could be simplified to `*s == '\0'`

Answer (score 0):

Given a `char *x="     ";` here is what I can suggest:

```
bool onlyspaces = true;
for(char *y = x; *y != '\0'; ++y)
{
    if(*y != '\n') if(*y != '\t') if(*y != '\r') if(*y != ' ') { onlyspaces = false; break; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

bool is_blank(const char* c)
{
    while (*c)
    {
       if (!isspace(*c))
           return false;
       c++;
    }
    return false;
}

int main ()
{
  char name[256];

  std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
  std::cin.getline (name,256);
  if (is_blank(name))
       std::cout << "No name was given." << std:.endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str`, `*c`, `c` which is it? :-)

Comment: @pmg: Only `str` is wrong. `*c` is the value of `c`, so it's ok! But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

```
int is_empty(const char *s)
{
    while ( isspace(*s) && s++ );
    return !*s;
}
```

with a [**working example**](http://ideone.com/Rtn6Yh).

1. Loops over the characters of the string and stops when

   - either a non-space character was found,
   - or nul character was visited.
2. Where the string pointer has stopped, check if the contains of the string is the nul character.

In matter of complexity, it's linear with O(n), where n the size of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

For C++11 you can check is a string is whitespace using [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and [`isspace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) (isspace checks for spaces, tabs, newline, vertical tab, feed and carriage return:

```
std::string str = "     ";
std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace); //this returns true in this case
```

if you really only want to check for the character space then:

```
std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](const char& c) { return c == ' '; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with strspn in one pass (just bool expression):

```
char *s;
...
( s[ strspn(s, " \r\n\t") ] == '\0' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sscanf to look for a non-whitespace string of length 1.  sscanf will then return -1 if it only finds whitespace.

```
char test_string[] = " \t\r\n";    // 'blank' example string to be tested
char dummy_string[2];   // holds the first char if it exists
bool isStringOnlyWhiteSpace = (-1 == sscanf(test_string, "%1s", dummy_string));
```