# Empty whitespace in array not recgnised C++ C

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have a `char` array of size 7 that looks like this...

```
Sean
Sam
Smith
Dave
Daniel
(empty line)
(empty line)
```

I basically want to read my `char` array size as `5` and discard the empty line whitespace.

This is my code, but it returns `7` and not `5`

```
int d=0;    
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(line[i]," ") == 0) // THIS LINE IS NOT RECOGNIZING THE WHITESPACE EMPTY LINES
    {
        d--;
    }
    else
    {
        d++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those two lines are exactly `" "`?

Comment: Your code requires the line to contain a single space. If it's _empty_ (i.e. no characters) the comparison will fail. Remember spaces and newlines are different characters. You need to check for both of them if you expect the string to contain either.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The lines are empty, but I don't know how to compare to empty lines

Comment: You obviously don't have a char array of size 7, as those names are quite a bit longer than 1 character each. Also, why is this tagged `c++`?

Comment: Strings are typically null terminated. If it's an empty string....

Comment: How are you reading your lines? If you are using `fgets`, I believe it will leave the line terminator in the resulting string. You may have to account for that.

Comment: If it contains a space then its not empty! Try: `strcmp(line[i],"")`.

Comment: also I am afraid, if it recognizes the empty strings, it will return 3, not 5...

Comment: @Captain Obvlious Note: In C, strings are not only typically null terminated, they are always null terminated.  "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character" C11 §7.1.1 1  OTOH, arrays of `char` are not always null terminated.

Comment: Only `Sean`, `Sam`, and `Dave` will survive if you limit you array size to `5` (the trailing `null-terminator` needs space too)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isspace()` function and iterate over your string, like that ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3981593/963881)):

```
int is_empty(const char *s) {
  while (*s != '\0') {
    if (!isspace(*s))
      return 0;
    s++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Or `while (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) s++; return *s == '\0';`

Comment: What about in context to the question I asked? line is declared as a `char**` array.

Comment: You can go from where, just pass the right pointer to the `is_empty()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your example suggests you think "space" is "whitespace". Addressing your code example (and ignoring the decrement of `d` when line is a "space")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *line[7] = {"Sean", "Sam", "Smith", "Dave", "Daniel", "", ""};

int main() {
    int i, d=0;    
    char *sptr;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)  {
        sptr = strtok (line[i], "\r\n\t ");  //extract from whitespace
        if (sptr)                            // any pointer?
            if (*sptr)                       // any text?
                d++;                         // count textual lines
    }
    printf ("%d\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```